# How to know if a LaTeX file needs another compilation pass

Tags: compiling, latexmk

When preparing a document some LaTeX files need more than one compilation pass.

This is for instance the case when the file is using `\tableofcontents`, `\ref`, or bibliography file (in which case a call to `bibtex` and two calls to `(pdf)latex`).

Is there a simple and generic way (in shell) after a call to `(pdf)latex` to know if some more calls are needed?

Comment: Read the log file. LaTeX warns you about these.

Comment: The `latexmk` checks to see if certain aux files change between to consecutive compilations. If they do not, the data can be assumed to be up to date.

Comment: Normally the `.log` will quite prominently say something like please "Rerun to get cross-references right" or "Please rerun LaTeX". If you cannot be bothered to scour the log file, you might as well run LaTeX again, just to be sure or rely on automatic tools such as `arara` or `latexmk`.

Comment: I now that there are information in the log file. My question could be understand as : "is there some normalized way to warn the user in the log file, so that I can parse it and make a script automatically know if the file needs to be recompiled or not?" or "is there a way a program (mainly shell script) can determine if a file need more compilation?".

Comment: In fact it is possible for a LaTeX file to endlessly "oscillate" between two different typeset documents. For example if you number footnotes starting at 1 on each page, a footnote may keep flipping between the bottom of one page and the top of the next, and every pass produces the "wrong" footnote numbers which don't correspond with the page the footnote has been moved to. The fix is to force a line or page break somewhere to eliminate one of the possibilities. `texify` is another tool similar to `arara` and `latexmk`.

Comment: @BrunoBEAUFILS that's what `latexmk` is. It is a `perl` script which "knows" quite a lot about how to build LaTeX documents. It can be customized if you want to run software that it doesn't know about as part of the build process. Basically it calculates MD5 checksums for all the files that are output during a pass of LaTeX, including all the temporary files like `.toc`, `.aux`, `.ind`, etc., and reruns LaTeX until the checksums don't change.

Comment: Thank's @alephzero. I know `latexmk` but would like to try avoid using it. In fact I am trying to construct a simple `makefile` doing an equivalent work but with just classical Unix tools (`sed`, `grep`, etc.).

Comment: I just run `latexmk` from a make file with two lines like ,`%.pdf: %.tex` `latexmk -xelatex -pdf $<` plus more rules with no commands for the files that the `.tex` file depends on.

Answer (score 10):

### Rerun warnings/hints in the console/log file

Often LaTeX or packages tell, when another LaTeX run is needed. But there are packages (TikZ/tikzmark), which do not implement the check, whether something has changed, thus that another LaTeX run should be done.

Example of LaTeX, when a label is new or has changed:

```
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

Example of package `biblatex`:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                test
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

The format of these messages is free and up to the package author, there is no standard for this. I recommend, that the message contains `rerun` or `Rerun` to follow most of these messages.

### Package `rerunfilecheck`

The idea of package `rerunfilecheck` is that if the input files are the same, then the result will be the same. It can be configured to watch auxiliary files.
At the begin, a checksum is calculated via pdfTeX's `\mdfivesum`. Then the auxiliary file is written during the normal LaTeX run. At the end the checksum is again calculated and compared. A rerun warning is given, when the checksums do not match.

For example, `hyperref` uses the package to watch the `.out` file for the bookmarks:

```
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `test.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.
```

### Heuristics

All these methods are heuristics. The language of TeX is too powerful (Turing complete). Therefore a program does not exist, that can decide, how many runs a TeX document needs. For example, there can be TeX documents, where the auxiliary files always change, but the result document is always the same. Or the result document is ten times the same, but changes in the eleventh run.